# Going Backwards

Tags: uninstall

I want to uninstall Desktop 18.04 and go back to 16.04 or 14.  I cannot get my old PC to boot 18.04 except by using "advanced options", it worked well with older versions.

How can I go back to an older version? A link to directions or a download would be great.

Comment: don't rollback to 14.04, this version will be EOL in few months, so if you have some problem to boot with 18.04, select 16.04; do you have some files / software to keep? If not, you can do a fresh install with an USB stick

Comment: There is no easy downgrade method. Instead you should backup every file, that you want to keep (documents, photos, multimedia files etc). Instead I suggest that you download and check one or two iso files, check it with md5sum, make a USB live drive and test it 'Try without installing' and after that install the version that works best for you. See this link, [How to select the version and flavour of Ubuntu](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13540865#post13540865)

Comment: Your only option is to re-install or to restore a disk dump you made yourself before upgrading/installing Ubuntu. But would it not be better to fix you problem. "except by using "advanced options" means a normal boot is possible too. Check /var/log/ on newly created log entries that show errors.

Comment: @RonH What do you mean by "using "advanced options"". Did selection of previous kernel version make system to boot and operate normally? If it is possible, please boot this way and add output of `ls /boot` and `uname -a` to the question.

Comment: I use GRUB and selected "advanced options" during the boot process and then clicked on an option for recovery mode.  After installing 18.04 it has never booted normally.  I have an old PC with a 1.7 GHz pentium so that is a contributor to the problem.  Hence, I probably should install an older version of UBUNTU Desktop.

Comment: Thank you all for the help.  Rinzwind, how do I check /var/log

Comment: In an old computer it is a good idea to try, and if it works well, install an Ubuntu community flavour with a light desktop environment, Lubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie, Ubuntu MATE or Xubuntu. But I suggest that you try 16.04.1 LTS or 18.04.1 LTS instead of older versions.